# Bash - here string quits after supplying arguments

Tags: bash, gdb

I am trying to open a GDB session and auto-execute some GDB commands to prepare my debugging session. So I wrote a script and I used a "here string" inside my script like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb <<< $'\ndashboard -layout source\n dashboard source -style context 14\nfile program.elf\ntarget remote :2331\nmonitor reset'
```

The GDB commands are sepparated with newline characters `\n` and are executed normaly, but after the last GDB command `monitor reset` I get a `quit` command which I didn't supply to GDB:

[image]

How can I prevent this command to take me out of GDB? I want to hand controll back to the user after the last command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quit` command is due to the end of standard input. The here string is like a file redirected as standard input. It seems you want to cat this string with standard input. The easiest may be using a file

```
cat file - | arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

where `file` contains the commands and `-` is a special argument for cat to use standard input.

otherwise using the string where `'...'` is the string

```
{ echo '...'; cat; } | arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

Comment: I used your second example and `cat` at the end does miracles. One more thing. Why do I get thos binary characters in my output *(look at my image)*?